# what does the error "no exception supplied" mean?

Tags: python, django, exception

My Django app is currently throwing this error on one of my pages, does anyone know what it eans?  I would supply more detail but I don't know what this error means so I'm not sure what the relevant files are and Django apps are rather large in the amount of code spread around so I'll post some code once I can get an idea of what this means.  Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I tried capturing the error and printing it like so:
EDIT: I've entered the code that's throwing the error

jobIDs is a dict containing all of the IDs of the records I want to modify

```
for i in jobIDs:  
    dateToRun = request.POST['dateToRun']
    timeToRun = request.POST['timeToRun']  
    try:
        if len(request.POST['dateToRun']) <= 0:
            dateToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()['whenToRun'].split(' ')[0]
        if len(request.POST['timeToRun']) <= 0:
            timeToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()['whenToRun'].split(' ')[1]
    except BaseException, e:
        print str(e)
    whenToRun = dateToRun + ' ' + timeToRun
    Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).update(whenToRun=whenToRun)
```

This produces a blank line of output (from the print in the except block), am I misunderstanding how to print out the error?

Comment: Can you post the full error message as well as the code inside the `try` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you executing a piece of code that may throw an exception? Perhaps a database query for something that does not exist? If so, you will need to wrap the block of code in a try/except clause. For example, if the exception is indeed a query for something that does not exist:

```
try: 
    #Block of code that throws exception
except Object.DoesNotExist:
    #Handle error
```

Comment: updated original post with my attempt to produce an error output.

Comment: Strange, does this solve the problem on the page or are you still getting the No Exception Supplied error?

Comment: Your question is answered, correct? Adding the except clause is the solution to the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I've been working through a bunch of questions simultaneously and I completely forgot about this one.  And yes, this helped me find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's because you're using `BaseException` instead of just `Exception`? Try this:

```
try:
    # Your code that may throw an exception
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

As per the [Python Exception docs on `BaseException`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions#exceptions.BaseException):

> exception BaseException
>
> directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use Exception)The base class for all built-in exceptions. It is not meant to be directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use [`Exception`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions#exceptions.Exception)).

Comment: In python 3.5: `except Exception as e:print (str(e))`